# Security Awareness Training Ideas

Tags: user-education, professional-education

Does anyone have any solid recommendations for deploying and maintaining security awareness training? I am not looking for a specific vendor but I am trying to gain insight about how the material is actually presented and how to test people on what they have learned.

We are a distributed company of 350 so hands on training probably won't work out.

Comment: Asking for vendor recommendations will tend to get a question closed down.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a link](http://msisac.cisecurity.org/resources/videos/free-training.cfm) to a plethora of content (most if not all free). SANS has some pretty good content, but the best content you can provide is the one you create. This is because what you are looking for is so broad, it will be too much for the average person to swallow, which will ultimately defeat the point.

There is [NIST SP800-50](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-50/NIST-SP800-50.pdf), but again, these tend to be so broad, they become 1) boring and 2) ignored. It helps immensely to personalize training around your business, not what others have made for theirs (NIST, CoBIT, ITIL) since all businesses have different goals, objectives, etc. What I have found, is that building one's own, and sending out N amount of reminders via say e-mail, works best.

I will share a story with you I had when I went for a pentest to a financial reporting company. Upon entering a company in MA, higher level management was skeptical of MOST security concepts. I explained things in analogies which helped them 'get it'. After discussing things for about an hour, they showed me a life-sized cut out poster of someone standing behind someone else holding a gun. It was a cartoony/video game like poster, but menacing. The intended message was: "this armed guy you don't see wants your password." The conveyed messages: 1) Hackers are gonna kill us 2) Security is blown out of proportion, no hackers run around with guns 3) What video game is that from?

Analogies work wonders. The average colleague is not going to immerse themselves on things like: AV*EF, Cipher-block Chaining, differences between EDE EEE, etc., however if you format it in a way that makes sense, and can carry over OUTSIDE OF WORK (e.g., how it can help keep their personal bank accounts, and personal info safe), it will work 1000x better.